# Adding private domains for sending without additional dedicated IP

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, sender-authentication-package, reputation, ip-warming

Right now we have 1 private domain and 1 dedicated IP (as part of the SAP we purchased while ago). We already did IP warm up using this private domain 3 years ago and have sent large volumes of email sends since then without any sending reputation or spam issues.

We would like now to add additional private domains for other brands we have as well. Those new private domains will use the same sending IP address we have been using so far (without purchasing additional dedicated IP for them).

**The question is - what can be the implactions in this case (using the same already used IP for new purchased private domains)?**

**Can the repuation of our existing sending IP be damaged from that? If so - in what ways?**

Thanks,

Barak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normally not a huge issue. You are however not mentioning any details on domain structure nor specific volumes.

Given you are sending e.g. 100.000 emails per week on your old PD, and want to shift 10-20.000 of these to the new PD, you should be fine. If you want to start sending 500.000 emails per week on the new PD, you might want to do a ramp-up over few weeks (3-4).

Other aspect, which not many are aware of, is the relationship between your SAP domain and private domain - in context of DMARC. Let's assume you are sending from email.example.com today:

- SAP domain populates the bounce domain: bounce.email.example.com
- Your new private domain populates the from domain: brand2.com
- **DMARC fail** because example.com does not equal brand2.com

What would work:

- SAP domain populates the bounce domain: bounce.email.example.com
- Private domain populates the from domain: brand2.example.com
- **DMARC pass** because in both cases they use the domain example.com

So in the past this was only safe if all domains involved were part of the same domain name - or if you did not implement DMARC on those domains. There is a new feature called multi-bounce domain. When that is enabled, the system will always change the bounce domain setting to be bounce.[from domain] - like this:

- From domain: brand2.com
- Bounce domain auto-set to: bounce.brand2.com

Hence you can use a PD different from your SAP domain. Multi bounce is enabled upon request, by submitting a support case requesting help setting up multi-bounce domain support for your new private domain.

Comment: Hi Lukas Lunow, thanks for your detailed answers. Few questions regarding it: 1. Is DMARC enabled on default when purchasing SAP SKU? We haven't find anything regarding it in the documentation (we found only mention of SAP domain being authinmcated by SPF and DKIM). 2. If the answer to question 1 is true - when purchasing new private domains shouldn't the support in default enable the multi-bounce domain option? This doesn't make sense. 3. What about using existing IP (we send ~50-80k email a week) for those new PDs. Can adding new PDs affect the reputation of this IP? Thanks

Comment: DMARC has been enabled per as default only on recent configurations. You can check if your SAP domain has DMARC configured [here](https://mxtoolbox.com/dmarc.aspx). I can't speak in details about how this configuration is done at Salesforce, but I would explicitly ask to have it enabled - just to be on the safe side. How big a percentual increase will 50-80k/week be?

Comment: Thanks Lukas again. 1. DMARC is not enabled in our sub-domain used for sends. Right now our deliverabilty isn't affected much by that. Can you think of explanation for that? 2. Right now we're sending 50-80k email per week. We plan to send additional 150-300k emails per week using the new PDs purchased. Do you recommend us purchase another IP SKU? SF responded to us that our planned volumes are too low for 2 IPs.

Comment: Continue from last comment: however we want to protect the repuation of our existing IP since: 1. The volume of sends will be much higher. 2. The brands used for the new PDs are completly differenet in nature to the current brand we use for our existing PD. Will users reporting our emails as spam with our new PDs affect our IP repuation?

Comment: You don't need extra IP. You will want to do a small "IP warmup" on these new PDs. Not specifically due to them being a new sender on your IP, but more due to the sudden spike in your volume. I would also have recommended it, if you had same spike on your existing setup (sending from your SAP domain). Unless I ready your plan incorrectly, and the volume is a target volume, which you will not achieve until 3-6 months down the line, then you should be fine just starting sending. But do enable DMARC on all your domains.

Comment: Thanks Luckas. One last question - will spam complainants from users can affect negatively our  IP reputation? This is the main reason we've considered purchasing new IP since we know the new brands which uses the new PDs are more susceptible to spam complaints by users receiving the emails. We afraid this impact negatively our IP reputation. Thanks again

Comment: Best practice is ALWAYS to keep spam complaints low. So far, I am yet to find an account where IP reputation has been severely affected by spam complaints alone. It is in 90% due to sudden and extreme spikes in volume. I will always prefer having one IP with high volume, over two with each semi-low volumes.