# Use SAP domain from different SFMC instances

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, deliverability, sender-authentication-package

I need to know if I can use an existing domain configured as SAP in SFMC Instance 1. Use it in SFMC instance 2 as SAP.
My intention is that both SFMC accounts coexists for some time using same SAP domain.

SFMC1: SAP domain - email.company.com
SFMC2: SAP domain - email.company.com

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible. The reason being, is the SAP domain covers not only the sender domain, but also open and click tracking. When someone clicks on your link, following https://click.email.company.com tracking domain, it can only go to a single instance of your Marketing Cloud.

The same goes for open tracking pixel.

As you want to run two instances simultaneously with the same SAP, you can't be sure which instance performed the send, hence where the click should be recorded.

You should be able to use same Private Domain on multiple instances, but few things need to be observed. Firstly, since you will be using same Private Domain on different SAP domains, you need to reach out to Salesforce Support to ask for enabling multi-bounce domain, as [described here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/319543/36623). Also, I am not sure how Reply Mail Management would work, if same Private Domain is applied on multiple instances. This is definitely an edge case I haven't experienced before, hence you might want to have it validated with Salesforce support regardless.

Comment: Thank you Lukas, makes completely sense. Following that logic, I suppose that same send domain can be used in different SFMC accounts as Registered domain and private domain. Is this correct?

Comment: @AgustinRodriguez - I have updated my answer with more details about this.